# Why ATX PSU is using separate ground wires?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, wiring

Why ATX PSU is using separate ground wires (black, that connects to mobo via 24pin ATX, to cpu via ESP mini-fit molex, to video cards via 6 or 8pin molexes)? Instead of just using chassis as a ground? Does ground wires create ground loop with chassis? I heard ground loops are generally bad idea.. so why?

Comment: So you think that connecting every single component in the computer to the chassis using a separate wire would be neater than adding a single wire to the existing cable? Even apart from the electrical implications this would be horrible :)

Answer (score 9):

ATX PSUs use a lot of ground wires because the system has a lot of separate loads, and every feed needs a return path. The chassis are usually made of ferrous sheet metal, and have higher resistance than copper. And yes, there could be unwanted ground offsets and cross-talks between nets with different consumers.  Instead of using a single finger-thick-size return ground, ATX supply uses many smaller ground wires, which distribute the return current more evenly, and make the cabling more flexible and manageable.

Answer (score 3):

> Why ATX PSU is using separate ground wires (black, that connects to
>   mobo via 24pin ATX, to cpu via ESP mini-fit molex, to video cards via
>   6 or 8pin molexes)?  Instead of just using chassis as a ground?

The chassis would be a bad way to return the current back to the source. Screws can cause problems because they can conduct current poorly if they don't make good contact. Often there is paint or other materials that can cause the resistance to go up. Wires are the best option, plus you wouldn't be able to take the power supply out of the chassis while it was powered up.

> Does ground wires create ground loop with chassis? I heard ground
>   loops are generally bad idea.. so why?

Ground loops are bad because it creates common mode noise, which could raise the voltage of one side of the loop more than the other should a magnetic field flow through the loop. However,there is not a better option to get power to the card or device when you need amps of current, the PCI connectors can only support ~10W cables can support much more. So how do you avoid killing digital signals with a ground loop? Computers are already designed to be tolerant to noise that might arise from a ground loop by using differential signaling.

[image]
Source: [Audiophileaddicts](http://www.audiophileaddicts.com/2014/09/hum-maybe-just-ground-loop/)

The signaling inside of a computer is already very noise tolerant, a computer is probably one of the worst environments for noise because you can have billions of transistors switching on and off which creates a lot of noise. Most of the chip to chip (PCI Express) or device to device (SATA) uses a [differential signalling pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling) which eliminates grounding problems.

Differential signaling is resistant to offsets in the ground that might arise from a common mode problem.

[image]